# How can I repeat my loop and add more information to my dictionary, and use different strings?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program so that I can input all the shifts I work in a week, and it will calculate the total number of hours I work, and how much I money I will make.

I have created a dictionary called week_schedule and an input prompt to ask the user what day of the week they are going to log. The program then asks the shift start and finish, creating variables for both of them, and storing it all in a dictionary.

How can I rerun this loop, so that I can input more than one day, and store it all in a dictionary that I can then print out later? Currently rerunning the loop just adds more information to the same strings.

```
week_schedule = {}

    day = input("Day of the week: ")

    day_promp = True

    while day_promp:
        dayStart = input("Shift Start: ")
        dayEnd = input("Shift End: ")

        dayHours = (float(dayEnd) - float(dayStart)) / 100
        dayPay = (float(dayHours) * 15.75)

        week_schedule[day] = format(dayHours) + " hours", "$ " + format(dayPay)

        repeat = input("\nMore days?: ")
        if repeat == 'no':
            day_promp = False

print("\n--- Week summary ---")
for day, dayHours in week_schedule.items():
    print(format(day) + ": " + format(dayHours))
    print("Total earned: $" + format(dayPay))
```

Currently I can run the program and it works for only one day.
For example if I imputed 'Tuesday" for the day, "1200" for the shift start, and "1800" for the shift end, it would output the following:

```
--- Week summary ---
Tuesday: ('6.0 hours', '$ 94.5')
Total earned: $94.5
--------------------
```

I would like to be able to print out all the days I input in the dictionary as well.

Comment: I wouldn'd do it with `input()`, because after inputting data for 5 days at least you will be tired of typing in data ...

Comment: Rather use an input file where you store information in a tabular form.

Comment: Your `day = input("Day of the week: ")` is only assigned once, so you have to do it every iteration in the loop, otherwise, you're just placing a new value under same key.

Comment: You need actually a file - to which you write your data - because you want the program to run next time - and still remember all information from previous session. So you should store the data not in a dictionary but into a file in a tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `day = input("Day of the week: ")` inside the loop, so it will be

```
week_schedule = {}
grand_total = 0
day_promp = True

while day_promp:
    # Do it each iteration
    day = input("Day of the week: ")
    dayStart = input("Shift Start: ")
    dayEnd = input("Shift End: ")

    dayHours = (float(dayEnd) - float(dayStart)) / 100
    dayPay = (float(dayHours) * 15.75)
    # sum up all the totals
    total += dayPay  

    week_schedule[day] = format(dayHours) + " hours", "$ " + format(dayPay)

    repeat = input("\nMore days?: ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        day_promp = False

print("\n--- Week summary ---")
# Now your dict has a key per day, so all values are printed.
for day, dayHours in week_schedule.items():
    print(format(day) + ": {} ".format(dayHours))
    print("Total earned: $ {0:.2f}".format(dayPay))

print("Grand Total earned $ {0:.2f}".format(total))
```

Your original code assigns `day = input("Day of the week: ")` only once, that's why
you're always getting only one value.

Comment: Is there anyway I can total all the money made from everyday I input?

Comment: See the grand total example in the edited version. Notice the `{0:.2f}` to format a float.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, the easiest way to make a program like this would be to have it write to a file in a given format. For example:

```py
WagePerHour = 9.50
Mode = input("Would you like to log another day, clear the log, or see the current total?  ")
if Mode == "log":
    EnterMore = True
    while EnterMore == True:
        Day = input("What day of the week are you logging?  ")
        Hours = input("How many hours did you work?  ")
        Days = { "Sunday" : "1", "Monday" : "2", "Tuesday" : "3", "Wednesday" : "4", "Thursday" : "5", "Friday" : "6", "Saturday" : "7"}
        File = open("File", "a")
        DayAsNumber = Days[Day]
        File.write(DayAsNumber + " " + Hours)
        File.write("\r\n")
        File.close()
        continuevar = input("Would you like to log another day? (Y/N)  ")
        if continuevar != "Y":
            EnterMore = False
if Mode == "total":
    File = open("File", "r")
    TotalHours = 0
    for line in File.readlines():
        if line[2:] != "":
            TotalHours += int(line[2:])
            TotalHoursString = str(TotalHours)
            print("So far this week, you have logged " + TotalHoursString + " hours.")
            File.close()
            TotalHoursAsInt = int(TotalHoursString)
            TotalWages = (TotalHoursAsInt * WagePerHour)
            TotalWagesString = str(TotalWages)
            print("Your wages before taxes are " + TotalWagesString)
        else:
            print("You have not logged any hours this week.")
if Mode == "clear":
    File = open("File", "w")
    File.write("")
    File.close()
```

Comment: It works perfectly, except when I try to view the total. Then I get the error:    TotalHours += int(line[2:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: That error only occurs if there are no days logged. I'll go ahead and add a fix for that.